# Add notice with ajax when user select local pickup shipping method on WooCommerce cart and checkout pages

Tags: ajax, woocommerce, cart, checkout, shipping-method

I'm making a plugin for an client, integrated with WooCommerce, and I need to add a notice, with `wc_add_notice`, when a local pickup shipping method is selected on cart and checkout pages.

I've tried adding a hook to `woocommerce_shipping_method_chosen` action, like this:

```php
add_action("woocommerce_shipping_method_chosen", "local_pickup_notice", 10, 1);
function local_pickup_notice($chosen_method){
    $woocommerce = WC();
    $shipping_method = $woocommerce->session->get("chosen_shipping_methods")[0];

    if($shipping_method == "local_pickup"){
        wc_add_notice(__("Local pickup shipping", "myplugin"), "notice");
    }
}
```

But, it didn't work. No notice is showing on cart or checkout page when a local pickup is selected (also when changing shipping method).

Can anyone help me with this?

**-- EDIT 1 --**

I've noticed that `woocommerce_shipping_method_chosen` isn't fired, so I change action hook to `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees`. Now, the action is fired, but still not showing the message.

Also tried changing from `wc_add_notice` to `wc_print_notice`, without success.

**-- EDIT 2 --**

My mistake was on checking the `$shipping_method`, because I have two `local_pickup` options. This way, the string stored on `$shipping_method` is `local_pickup:<option_id>` instead of only `local_pickup`. So, changing the `if` statement to use `strpos` instead `==` makes it working.

The current result is:

```php
add_action("woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees", "local_pickup_notice", 10, 1);
function local_pickup_notice($cart){
    $woocommerce = WC();
    $shipping_method = $woocommerce->session->get("chosen_shipping_methods")[0];

    wc_clear_notices();

    if(strpos($shipping_method, "local_pickup") !== false){
        wc_add_notice(__("Local pickup shipping", "myplugin"), "notice");
    }
}
```

Now, it's working, but ONLY when the cart/checkout page is loaded. The next challenge is to make this work on the AJAX call, to show the notice when user changes shipping method.

If someone knows how to add notice on WooCommerce ajax, please tell me

Answer (score 0):

`wc_add_notice` should be used in hooks that allow you to handle your custom AJAX endpoints. Certainly not in the `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees` hook, that hook is used for other purposes.

To add a notice when user select local pickup as shipping method, you can use:

```php
// jQuery - Ajax script
function action_wp_footer() {
    // Only cart & checkout pages
    if ( is_cart() || ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) ) {
        $js_variable = is_cart() ? 'wc_cart_params' : 'wc_checkout_params';

        // jQuery Ajax code
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($) {
            if ( typeof <?php echo $js_variable; ?> === 'undefined' )
                return false;
            
            // Get chosen shipping method
            var c_s_m = $( 'input[name^="shipping_method"]:checked' ).val();
            
            // Function that sen the Ajax request
            function sendAjaxRequest( c_s_m ) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: <?php echo $js_variable; ?>.ajax_url,
                    data: {
                        'action': 'chosen_shipping_method',
                        'chosen_shipping_method_val': c_s_m
                    },
                    success: function ( result ) {
                        // Remove other notices
                        $( '.woocommerce-info' ).remove();
                        
                        // Display notices cart
                        $( '.woocommerce-cart-form' ).before( result );                     
                        
                        // Display notices checkout
                        $( 'form.checkout' ).before( result );
                        
                        // console.log(result); // Uncomment for testing
                    }
                });
            }
            
            // On ready (DOM loaded)
            sendAjaxRequest( c_s_m );

            // On live "change event"
            $( document.body ).on( 'change', 'input[name^="shipping_method"]', function() {
                sendAjaxRequest( $( this ).val() );
            });
        });
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'action_wp_footer', 10, 0 );

// Php Ajax
function chosen_shipping_method_handler() { 
    if ( isset( $_POST['chosen_shipping_method_val'] ) ) {
        $shipping_method = sanitize_key( $_POST['chosen_shipping_method_val'] );
        
        if ( strpos( $shipping_method, 'local_pickup' ) !== false ) {           
            // Add notice
            wc_add_notice( __( 'Local pickup shipping', 'woocommerce' ), 'notice' );
        }
    }
    
    // Return printed notices to jQuery response.
    wc_print_notices();
    
    // Alway at the end (to avoid server error 500)
    die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_chosen_shipping_method', 'chosen_shipping_method_handler' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_chosen_shipping_method', 'chosen_shipping_method_handler' );
```